# Mongoose TypeScript: Is String the correct data type for a foreign key?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

When making a collection in mongo to link collection is there any special type I need to use other than just string for the foreign key?
In the example below I am trying to establish a link between two users where the `userId` is following the `followingId`, I intend to create 1 document for each relation.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';

interface FollowingModelInterface extends Document {
  followingId: string; // <---- this will be the _id from the users table
  userId: string; // <---- this will be the _id from the users table
}

const followingSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    followingId: { type: String, index: true  }, // <----- is the type string correct?
    userId: { type: String, index: true }, // <----- is the type string correct?
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const followingModel = mongoose.model<FollowingModelInterface>('Following', followingSchema);
export { followingModel, FollowingModelInterface };
```

I will use this table to search for all the users that the `userId` is following, I will want to get more than just the `followingId` back, I will need the users `name` and `imageid` from the user's collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type of your foreign key should match the type of the key from the foreign document.

If you've not changed this it will most likely be an `ObjectId`.

You can then declare it as:

```
followingId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, index: true  }
```

Comment: Thank you, how about the Interface? is `followingId: string; ` right? The error I get is `Property 'ObjectId' does not exist on type 'typeof Schema'.ts(2339)`

Comment: @Bill Ideally you should use `Schema.ObjectId` throughout, including the interface. It has a `toString()` method which you can use to get a string where needed.

Comment: if I use `Schema.ObjectId` in the Interface I get the error `Namespace '"mongoose".Schema' has no exported member 'ObjectId'.ts(2694)`

Comment: @Bill can you try `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` in both the Interface and Document?